# Unable to use Google API explorer

Tags: google-workspace, google-admin-sdk, google-apis-explorer

I am trying to use the google explorer API to test the queries I am making, I find that access to the explorer API is blocked, the side panel is not displayed.
In addition, I have blocked access to the administration APIs.
I have opened a ticket to google but we still can't solve it after 2 months.

I have already checked in google workspace:

- Security>API controls
  and has no restrictions.
  the account is super admin.
  Access to other services without individual control is enabled in all organizational units.

Annex capture as it currently looks

[image: bug view]

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the fact that the age filter must be deactivated and the option of unmanaged apps enabled in the google workspace console